# Convertir numero hexadecimal a complemento 2 decimal

Tags: python, python-3.7

Tengo un numero en formato hexadecimal que al momento de convertirlo desde una [pagina](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html) me arroja unos resultados, uno es en decimal y otro el cual necesito dice "Decimal from signed 2's complement", este es el numero en decimal que tengo

```
xfffe
```

al convertirlo normalmente a decimal desde python

```py
byte=int('fffe')
byte=int(byte,16) #salida de 65534
```

Estoy buscando como transformarlo a ese complemento a 2, opte por preguntar acá para el que me pueda ayudar

Muchísimas gracias para el que me pueda ayudar.

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Aclara que sensor y plataforma (ESP32 o alguna otra) estás usando, a fin de chequear las librerias disponibles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complemento a 2 significa que el primer bit (más significativo) te indica si el valor es positivo (cero) o negativo (uno). Los restantes bits son el valor mismo.

Lo usual es convertir los bytes a entero como si un valor positivo, es decir, considerando el primer bit como parte del valor:

```
valor = int(val, 16)
```

La función `int` acepta un segundo argumento que es la base con lo cual interpretar `val`. Al usar 16, le decimos que el valor está en hexadecimal.

Eso funciona sin problemas para cualquier `val` entre `0000` y `7FFF`, que en decimal va desde 0 hasta 2 ** 15 - 1.

```
if valor > 2 ** 15 - 1:
```

Para valores entre `8000` y `FFFF` cometimos un error al incluir el primer bit dentro del cual. Hay que corregirlo restando ese bit, cuyo valor es 2 ** 16, con lo resulta el auténtico valor negativo:

```
valor -= 2 ** 16
```

Asi escribimos la función hex2int que recibe bytes y retorna un entero con signo:

```
def hex2int(val):
    valor = int(val, 16)
    if valor > 2 ** 15 - 1:
        valor -= 2 ** 16
    return valor


tests = [("05AA", 1450),
         ("FFFF", -1),
         ("FFFE", -2),
         ("0000", 0),
         ("B1E0", -20000),
         ("3FAC", 16300)]

for test in tests:
    hxe = test[0]
    val = test[1]
    res = hex2int(hxe)
    print(hxe, val, res)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDPCoMwDMbvfYrgyYpCq9PDwIEb@hLiYbCKwlDRbrin79I/brjl0vb7JWm@TC/ZjUOi1E200Ik17gfpP693eiSAgbdxhhycGgLPqAF969gJYggC4ClEwG3RtzDKHc0MmIV8zINlhBApFrlg89r3WFoUHnY/pIyGnybgexUGgoj/yaWW473MMFD@6XHmJTPJGu9RUhUX/W@WIGkIaXFoPRYaNudiHXWrwDm1ULNmW8ym8MaZ0162FWKFXdQ0u2cIZoGYRolSbw)

produce en cada línea el valor hex, su conversión y el valor esperado:

```
05AA 1450 1450
FFFF -1 -1
FFFE -2 -2
0000 0 0
B1E0 -20000 -20000
3FAC 16300 16300
```